# Print x/2 as 1/2 x in Sympy

Tags: python, sympy

How can I tell Sympy to print x/2 as 1/2 x for example? I.e. print a fraction as 1 over the denominator times the numerator?

Comment: is there a particular reason for this? They are equivalent after all.

Comment: @notcompletelyrational I just like the look of it more, and sympy has a lot of functionality to convert between 'equivalent' expressions.

Comment: Which printer are you using? The `latex` printer has some flags to control the printing of fractions, but the other ones do not (you'd have to subclass the printer to change them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this properly you would have to write your own printer, I believe. To do this hackishly you might try:

```
mul = x/2
a, b = mul.as_two_terms()
if a.is_Rational and not a.is_Integer:
    print (Mul(Symbol(str(a.p))/a.q, b, evaluate=False))
else:
    print (mul)
```